# Corona SDK: How to make an object move

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

I'm working on a game, in which I have a character that I want to move in the x axis when the screen is touched. I've managed to this however I want the object to continue to move for as long as the screen is being touched and not just move once. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an touch listener on the Runtime object:

```
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", buttonPressed)
```

or create an invisible button that covers the whole screen.

Comment: As I said, by doing that the character doesn't keep moving while screen is being touched.

Comment: You still need the enterFrame to go with it.  The touch just turns on a flag that the enterFrame needs to know if to move the character or not.

Comment: The enterFrame event doesn't seem to be triggered at any point

Comment: I meant the moveCharacter event

Answer (score 2):

Touch events in Corona SDK only happen when something changes, like when the touch began, ended, or a move of the finger was detected.  If you want to have something go on while a button is being held down, its going to require an "enterFrame" event.

```
local buttonPressed = false

local function moveCharacter(event)
    if buttonPressed then
        character.x = characterx + 1
    end
end

local function buttonPressed(event)
     if event.phase == "began" then
          buttonPressed = true
     elseif event.phase == "ended" then
          buttonPressed = false
     end
     return true
 end

 local myButton = display.newRect(0,0,64,48)
 myButton:addEventListenr("touch", buttonPressed)

 Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", moveCharacter)
```

In this scenario, the enterFrame listener will move the character when it sees the button's state as being pressed.  Now you may not want to move the character one pixel 30 times a second, so you will need to figure out just how many fractional pixels to move it.  Your buttonPressed then just becomes a way to turn on a flag to cause the move function to work.

Comment: I really do not want to add a button, I consider them a waste of space, isn't there arother way around it? I've looked into using translate but the character just flys off the screen.

Comment: Add an invisible button that covers the whole screen:

Comment: If I did that I would only be able to move the character in one direction